# QGIS Web Client Setup mapserv error?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I have my web map up and running and am now trying to clean up a few recurring errors in the qgis-web-client-error.log. The error in question is:

```
[error] [client 123.456.789.1] script not found or unable to start: /home/blank/qgis-web-client/cgi-bin/mapserv, referer: http://blank.com/qgiswebclient.html?map=/home/blank/qgis-web-client/projects/gf_utm.qgs&format=image/png&visibleLayers=paddocks,image,wheat_yield,allendale_cntr
```

When I look in GlobalOperations.js there is a line in Overview setting that I have not modified:

```
var overviewLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Pixelkarte",
"/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/path-to-map/.map",
{layers:"pk_kombiniert",format:"image/jpeg"},
{buffer:0,singleTile:true,transitionEffect:"resize"});
```

But I am not sure what path to put in here. Is it to qgis_mapserv.fcgi?  I do notice that my overview map does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to your server like:

```
mapbng.BlueMarblePlus = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("BlueMarble with Countries",
    "http://metadata.xxx.ac.uk/cgi-bin/gnWMS/wms?",{
    "layers":"BLUEMARBLE,gboundaries",
    "format":"image/png",
    "transparent":false
    },{
    "isBaseLayer":true,
    "displayOutsideMaxExtent":true
    }
);
```

In this example the map file location is known to the MapServer service configuration and the `mapserv` executable has been renamed as `wms`, but you would need to add the map file location so this would become:

```
mapbng.BlueMarblePlus = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("BlueMarble with Countries",
    "http://metadata.xxx.ac.uk/cgi-bin/gnWMS/mapserv?map=Full-path-to-map.map",{
    "layers":"BLUEMARBLE,gboundaries",
    "format":"image/png",
    "transparent":false
    },{
    "isBaseLayer":true,
    "displayOutsideMaxExtent":true
    }
);
```